# How can I mock static method of class using mockery?

Tags: laravel, phpunit, mockery

I have this class:

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers\Alerts;

 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
 use App\Models\Alert;
 use App\Models\FiredAlert;
 use App\Models\UnitReport;
 use App\Notifications\AlertSetup;
 use Carbon\Carbon;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;

 class AlertController extends Controller
 {

/**
 * @param Alert $alert
 * @param null $schema
 */
public static function checkForInactivity(Alert $alert, $schema = null): void
{
     ...some code...
}

/**
 * Get int day of the week
 * @return int
 */
public static function getDayOfTheWeek(): int
{
    return Carbon::now()->dayOfWeek;
}

/**
 * Get all alerts available fot the current day and process it
 */
public static function checkForInactivityAlerts(): void
{

    $alerts = Alert::where('day', self::getDayOfTheWeek())->get());
    foreach ($alerts as $alert) {
        self::checkForInactivity($alert);
    }
}
```

}

I would like to mock getDayOfTheWeek and checkForInactivity and call checkForInactivityAlerts, something like:

```
$mockAlertController = Mockery::mock("alias:App\Http\Controllers\Alerts\AlertController");
$mockAlertController->shouldReceive('getDayOfTheWeek')->andReturn(2);
$mockAlertController->shouldReceive('checkForInactivity')->once();
AlertController::checkForInactivityAlerts()
```

But I got the error:

> Mockery\Exception\BadMethodCallException : Static method
> App\Http\Controllers\Alerts\AlertController::checkForInactivityAlerts()
> does not exist on this mock object

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you have already see this https://github.com/mockery/mockery/issues/620 ?

Comment: Why do you even have to use static calls, with the way the container works why not just make a service class? and have the method non static?